# Powershell : set enviroment variable doubled

Tags: powershell, variables, path

The code below tries to change the enviroment variable PATH but unfortunately the strings are doubled :

> Blockquote
>   C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
>   C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
>   C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;;C:\LJ\jdk-13\bin
>   Blockquote

the ';C:\LJ\jdk-13\bin' is the only string I wanted to add

Do you know where is the error ?
Thanks

```
    $zip =  [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead($jdkDownloadPathName).Entries
    $jdkFolder = (($zip | Where-Object FullName -match '/' | Select-Object -First 1).Fullname -Split '/')[0]
    $jdkInstallFolder ="$($installJavaAntPath)\$($jdkFolder)"
    $PATH = $env:Path
    $PATH += ";" + $jdkInstallFolder +"\bin"
    Set-EnvironmentVariable -name PATH -Value $PATH -Target User 
    Set-EnvironmentVariable -name JAVA_HOME -Value $jdkInstallFolder -Target User
```

```
    function Set-EnvironmentVariable
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $Name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $Value,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [EnvironmentVariableTarget]
    $Target
  )
  [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($Name, $Value, $Target)
}
```

Comment: the path you get from `$env:Path` is for ALL the targets - machine + user + process. you only want to change ONE of them, so use the `Get` equivalent to your `Set` call. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank , I'm trying with  $p = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") I have two accounts ,maybe its this that cause double strings ?

Comment: nope, the double strings were caused by loading ALL the paths from `machine`, `user`, and `process` ... and then putting them all into ONE target. think about it - if `ThisThing` is in `user` and you add `OtherThing` to the _whole path_ ... and then save it to `machine` ... you will have two copies of `ThisThing`. the 1st will be from the `user` section, but the 2nd will be from the `machine` section.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how upvote your answer

Comment: you are very welcome! no need to upvote this one ... i'm quite pleased that i was able to help. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$PATH = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
    $PATH += ";" + $jdkInstallFolder +"\bin"
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH',$PATH, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
```

I have understood, thanks @Lee_Dailey!